# Postgres parallel seq scan making high CPU Utilization

Tags: postgresql-10, parallelism

When I run a select query which runs on a view in Postgres, it is starting 3 processes for a single query, which is causing high CPU utilization when multiple job runs in parallel.

How to avoid using parallel sequential scans and increase my query performance at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable parallel query by setting `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` to 0 in `postgresql.conf`.

Then the only ways of speeding up processing are

- keep the table cached in RAM
- avoid a sequential scan by creating an index

If possible, the second way is much better.